# minimagick No method "resize"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimagick

Rails noob here so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

We're replacing a lot of paperclip functionality with mini_magick.  It seemed pretty straight forward until I realized that for some reason the fact that we have a class called Image was blowing things up.

I renamed the Image class in MiniMagick and that fixed that problem, but then we also had a method called method_missing, which was also in MiniMagick.

Renamed all references etc., to magick_method_missing and now I'm getting the following error.

```
undefined method `resize' for #<MiniMagick::ImageEditor:0x2b236a98c9f8>
```

(ImageEditor is the renamed class).

This is my first time having to deal with plugins in our system.  All of my other experience has been really simple, "gem install ..."  lol.  Does anyone know what I might be missing?

For now I'm just going to go through the code line by line to see if I missed a reference somewhere.  That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Oh and I looked at all of the functions available to the object but it appears that it only has the object methods and nothing special.  Which I suppose is to be expected.

Comment: So you have a class MiniMagick::Image and another YourApp::Image the two are in different modules and wont conflict. You do know that monkey patching others code is generally considered bad practice right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you rename classes and methods in 3rd party code?

And `method_missing` is called whenever a method is not found. If I remember right MiniMagick uses it for calls to the binary, renaming it wont work, it has to be named `method_missing`.

As far as using a plugin goes, you can use the gem. Its homepage is [located here](http://rubygems.org/gems/mini_magick).

Comment: I think I would have an easier time if I could just install the gem straight into the app, but our IT won't let us install anything so we have to install on a local folder and then move the installation over by hand.  I was under the impression that plugins generally won't conflict with main apps, so why would minimagick cause all of our image calls to explode?

Comment: They shouldn't, revert your app to the version with the unmodified plugin and make a new post about the error. That should help you get an answer without having to modify other 3rd party code.

Comment: Resetting the gem back to base, I still get this error:
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Which I can't figure out since the line it's failing on is image_file.resize image_size (Where image_size is the string with the dimensions pulled from our db).  This is the same problem that got me to monkey patching in the first place, although for all I know this is probably an issue with our main app.  Our local Ruby expert recently left or I'm sure this issue wouldn't have been a big deal...

Comment: I'll ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imagemagick installed. I was getting the same error

```
undefined method `resize' for #<MiniMagick::ImageEditor:0x2b236a98c9f8>
```

I noticed I had imagemagick installed on my mac but old version. I had to uninstall and install again.

I used homebrew to uninstall old version and install imagemagick again:

```
brew unlink imagemagick
brew install imagemagick
```